Using Azure boards - user story gets auto assigned to me when I change the state. Is there a way to avoid?
I am using a custom process inherited from "Agile". If I change the state of a user story directly from the sprint board and the story is not assigned to anyone - it will automatically assign the user story to me.
Trying to see if its possible to remove this functionality but all posts about it tells me to check the custom rules for user story and there are no such rules.
So I'm looking for a way to remove this automatically assignment.

I managed to solve it myself - doing the opposite to all instructions out there:
-Go to organizational settings >> Process and select the process in use
-Find the work item type you want to change (I did it work all types we use)
-Go to "Rules"
-Add a rule with condition
--When "A work item state changes to..." "Active" and
--Action "Copy the value from ..." "Assigned To" to "Assigned To"
